# location of an object is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to go to another page using this function

```
function MButton1Click(event) {
alert("teste2");
window.location("teste.php");
}
```

but i'm getting

> location of an object is not a function

Comment: Well, error seems obvious. You're calling it as a function when it is not a function...

Comment: location is a property. Try window.location = "http://..."

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
window.location = "teste.php";
```

Your syntax is for functions.. `location()` however `location` is an object.

Take a look at the [window.location documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location)

Comment: something else is probably breaking your code before it gets to this statement. this is the way to do it. check out the docs.

Comment: `function MButton1Click(event) {
window.location.href = "www.google.com";}`

Comment: take `.herf` out. I put it by mistake and immediately deleted. let me know if it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) is an object. You can use its [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Methods) or [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Methods) functions to change pages:

```
// Use this if you want the back button to take you to the current page
window.location.assign("teste.php");

// Use this if you want to remove the current page from the browser's history
window.location.replace("teste.php");
```

You can also use the [assignment shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.231.3A_Navigate_to_a_new_page) for `assign`:

```
window.location = "teste.php";
```